# How can i create a class that inherits the methods from FILE

Tags: c++, file, inheritance

How would i extend the FILE class to use its methods? In other words, how can i use all of the functions that are provided with the default FILE object and still have the same functionality that mimics the actual functions?

Comment: Are you talking about the C `FILE` object? Why would you use that in C++? If you wanted to use it, you can't inherit from it (as it is not a C++ class), but you could wrap it in a class.

Comment: Yes the very FILE object. how would i do that? would i use a struct or something along those lines?

Comment: You could use RAII to create a `FILE` wrapper and then use that wrapper.

Comment: any links to examples that would work about the same?

Comment: `FILE` might be an opaque type (i.e. an incomplete type) so it would be non-portable to derive from it. Also I think it would be confusing to the user to derive from it, even if your compiler had it as a complete type.

Comment: Inherit `std::file_buf` instead.. Under the hood, this class itself also uses `FILE`: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/basic__file_8h-source.html

Answer (score 0):

```
class myFile
{
   File *_f;
public:
   myFile(File *f){ /*open the file here, then make _f=f;*/ };
   virtual ~myFile(){ /*close the file here*/ };
   // and can add more methods here
}
```